# C Function argument value changing by itself

Tags: c, memory-management, precision

I have a simple function that, after it has returned, the values of the array a[] (passed as argument) are changed. The problem is that they are not even written on in the function, only read - supposedly, at least -. Hope you can help me with that:

```
double *bhaskara(double a[]){
    double A = a[2], B = a[1], C = a[0];
    double raizes[2];
    double delta = B*B - 4*A*C;
    if(delta<=0){//ignora delta para pegar soh a parte inteira das raizes
        raizes[0] = -B/(2*A);
        raizes[1] = raizes[0];
    }else{
        raizes[0] = (-B+sqrt(delta))/(2*A);
        raizes[1] = (-B-sqrt(delta))/(2*A);
    }
    return raizes;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're returning a pointer to a local variable that has gone out of scope. It's undefined behaviour. Anything can, and will, happen.

Comment: lol, darn you beat me to it :) I was putting code sample.. :)

Answer (score 3):

You have a bigger issue here too:

```
 double raizes[2];
   .... function ....
 return raizes;
```

You are returning a pointer to a value that has been created on the stack for the local function.
Bad, never do that.

Pass and input and output array.

```
void bhaskara(const double a[], double raizes[]){
```

Comment: Thank you for not saying "use `malloc` inside the function and return that pointer". Best for ownership to not pass in and out of functions when possible.

Comment: on no..I hate creating memory if I do not need to, and if you do, I prefer to use shared_ptr..then again, I run away from malloc. 99% of the time you do not NEED to handle the memory yourself, it just causes leaks :(

Comment: Definitely in C++, but C doesn't have RAII, unfortunately, so you have to make do with expressing clear ownership in other ways.